# multiple graphics windows with gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

The `ggraphics()` constructor of the `gWidgets` package opens a plot window. Is it possible to open several plot windows and to control in which window we plot a graph ? (The help of `ggraphics()` says: *When multiple graphics devices are present, clicking in the window of one will make that the current device*. But I want to control the current device with the R code, not with the mouse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple `ggraphics` instances, each having its own device number to do all the things you want. The `ggraphicsnotebook` widget packages up an interface for this if you want. The bit about clicking on the window is in addition to the usual programmatic ways to specify the current device.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't see how to do with the help documentation. Do you have a link to an example ?